# How to finish this proof using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: induction, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

[image: This is what I get]

What should I do next?

I've tried to show that 
$n\sum_{i=1}^n a_i >= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i + n$ but it gets me to sth like: 
$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i >= \frac{n}{(n-1)}$

$a_1, a_2... \in R$

Comment: It looks like you've used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as if it said $(a\cdot b)^2\leq  \|a\|^2+\|b\|^2$, but that's not correct.

Comment: Yeah, now I see it.. thank you very much! What a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We are using that

- $u=\left(\frac{a_1}n,\frac{a_2}n,\dots,\frac{a_n}n\right)$
- $v=\left(1,1,\dots,1\right)$

then

$$|u\cdot v|^2=\left(\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}\right)^2\le|u|^2\cdot |v|^2=\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n^2}\cdot n$$

$$\iff\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}\le\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2}{n}}$$